# Destroy created beans on failure in ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext, spring-framework-beans

I use Springframework's ClassPathXMLApplicationContext to initialize some beans as follows:

```java
ctx = new ClassPathXMLApplicationContext(filename);
```

And I call `ctx.close()` on application exit.

However, sometimes the creation of ctx itself gives an exception (due to error in some bean creation) due to which I don't get the ctx object. But some of the beans might have initialized successfully before this exception.

My question is how do I do an equivalent of `ctx.close()` in this case to clean up the beans that might have got initialized?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 7 or later version then you can declare your context initialisation inside try with resources, so that you don't need to close context manually:

```
try(final AbstractApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(filename))
{
     //write your code
} catch(Exception e){}
```

Also, In a non-web application environment, you register a shutdown hook with the JVM. Doing so ensures a graceful shutdown and calls the relevant destroy methods on your singleton beans so that all resources are released. Of course, you must still configure and implement these destroy callbacks correctly.

To register a shutdown hook, you call the registerShutdownHook() method that is declared on the AbstractApplicationContext class:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
  AbstractApplicationContext ctx
      = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String []{"beans.xml"});

  // add a shutdown hook for the above context... 
  ctx.registerShutdownHook();

  // app runs here...

  // main method exits, hook is called prior to the app shutting down... }
```

**And Spring's web-based ApplicationContext implementations already have code in place to handle shutting down the Spring IoC container gracefully when the relevant web application is being shutdown.**

[source: spring-framework-reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html)